# Do I have to add the SecurityProtocol in front of every single Request? VB.Net / C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, security, protocols

Hey I have a Program that requests a URL and to fix SSL issues I found following code that I have to add in front of it:

```
Dim serverCertificateValidationCallback As [Delegate] = ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(se As Object, cert As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, sslerror As System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors) True
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType)
```

So do I have to add this code only once in the Main Forms Load Event or do I have to add it in each Function / Sub / Form?

Comment: TLS is used when you have a URL with HTTPS (secure).  The SecurityProtocol is used to set the default version of TLS for application and is only required once.

Comment: Setting `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` is only required in Windows versions prior to `8.1`. You should also post the Framework in use, since newer versions use the standard `SystemDefault`. Why do you also have this: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType)`? This was used with Framework versions prior to 4.5. The `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is used when you need to validate the Server certificates even if the certificate is invalid. Setting this: `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True` implies that you handle it. If you don't, set it to `false`

Answer (score 0):

`ServicePointManager` is static, so it only has to be set up once.  Consider, though:

[image]

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager?view=net-5.0

Comment: Where did you get the recommendation?  Since TLS 1.0/1.1 was disabled last June the only solution is to add the ServicePointManager.

Comment: Edited to add source.

Comment: There is no equivalent TLS method in HttpClient.  The recommendation is only for methods that have an equivalent HttpClient method.

Comment: @jdweng There is: `HttpClientHandler.SslProtocols`. You need to target .Net 4.7.2+. Anyway, people often confuse *recommended* with *mandatory*, for some reason. You still need to set the `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` in some specific cases (e.g., you're supporting Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008), if you want your code do work. Otherwise, you'd have to tweak the Registry.

Comment: @Jimi : You only need to use 4.7.2 if you are using TLS 1.3 and/or you want to use the operating system and not Net for the TLS.  TLS works very well below 4.7.2 if you are using TLS 1.2.

Comment: @jdweng That's not what I'm saying. Starting from .Net 4.7.2, you can set the SSL Protocol to HttpClient using the `HttpClientHandler.SslProtocols` property. Before that, it was GET only, setting it did nothing. After that, your can set the Property. So there's no need to set the ServicePoint using the general `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` (which applies to all connections). It's fully implemented in .Net 4.8 (and .Net 5, of course).